# Крутить ScrollView на всех item ах recycleView

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview, recycleview

В каждом итеме `recycleView` есть горизонтальный `ScrollView`. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при скролле `ScrollView` одного из итемов крутились и другие `ScrollView` на других итемах.

Синхронное прокручивание `ScrollView` во всех итемах `RecycleView`.

Вот такого вида `recycleView`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у Вас содержимое item'ов разной ширины? Может проще весь Recycler в ScrollView загнать?

Comment: думаю загнать RecycleView в HorizontalScrollView будет не то что нужно. Как нибедь синхронизировать бы все ScrollView во всех итемах

Comment: ну в теории наверное как-то так, получить событие прокрутки в onBindViewHolder, и передавать это значение во ViewHolder где у вашего ScrollView будет changeListener который будет прокручивать все скроллы одной переменной

Comment: Чуть ниже добавил, как сделал. Если есть соображения как лучше сделать, буду рад "услышать"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так. Не уверен что самый лучший вариант, но работает.

```
private List<HorizontalScrollView> horizontalScrollViews;
private HorizontalScrollView selectScrollView;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder v, final int position) {

    v.scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            selectScrollView = v.scrollView;
            return false;
        }
    });


    v.scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            if (v.scrollView!=selectScrollView) return;
            for (int i = 0; i < horizontalScrollViews.size(); i++) {
                horizontalScrollViews.get(i).scrollTo(v.scrollView.getScrollX(), 0);
            }
        }
    });        
    horizontalScrollViews.add(v.scrollView);

}
```